# New home stone facade moisture issue?

Tags: masonry, stone

I purchased a newly constructed home 6 months ago. I've begun noticing the stone facade on the front porch seeping moisture. The porch is covered, and the seeping happens independent of rain or snowfall. Any idea what could be causing this, and what I should be doing about it to prevent mold/moisture issues from becoming a problem?

[image: Porch stone facade moisture]

The moisture is around the whole of the porch, not just the spot pictures (which is the worst). I've included a couple more pictures below for reference.

Located in South Central PA. The house is under warranty, but as the homeowner I'd like to try and have an understanding of the root cause of this so that I can feel comfortable with, or pushback on, whatever the builder recommends.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Contact the builder, since it is his problem to fix.  It might be a plumbing problem if there are pipes in/near that wall, or a roof leak.

Comment: @crip659 I've considered the roof leak, and even the plumbing possibilities, but the moisture is fairly evenly distributed across the whole porch, even in a corner separated by a door. It really seems like an installation issue to me. I was hoping that a mason could weight in...

Comment: Most new homes, it seems, come with a warranty. You've paid a lot for the house (even if it was a cheapie!) so may as well take advantage of that if you've got one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I should have mentioned in my post that I already reached out to the builder. However, I'd really like to understand why it's happening before blindly trusting whatever solution they intend to offer.

Comment: Should edit this information into your question.  It does change the question enough.  Your general location will help also.  Those moisture stains do need a source of water.

Comment: @crip659, you're right. Post updated.

Comment: You might be better off posting a question asking about the pros/cons of the approach the builder offers than asking for speculation on something we can't get our hands on...

Comment: How long has it been since it rained? Does all of the stone area get wet when it does?

Comment: @isherwood I know it hasn't rained for several days, but I can't remember the last time specifically.

Comment: I assume you don't have active sprinklers. I would get a cheap little surveillance camera that can record 12 hours (even a frame every 5 minutes) and watch to see how the moisture accumulates. I suspect dew combined with poorly sloped concrete. Take a torpedo level out there (or a garden hose) to check the concrete slope.

Comment: @popham really good thought. Checked with a level and things are properly sloped away from the house. No sprinklers. I’m starting to become concerned that the porch roof isn’t flashed properly and we’re getting a bunch of water behind the siding and facade.